# If $\sup_n$ $E|X_n|^{1+\sigma} \lt \infty$ for $\sigma \gt $0, then $\{|X_n|\}$ is uniformly integrable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

If $\sup_n$ $E|X_n|^{1+\sigma} \lt \infty$ for $\sigma \gt $0, then $\{|X_n|\}$ is uniformly integrable.

I've seen a similar problem without the exponent on $|X_n|^{1+\sigma}$ and tried to apply it here but I think I might be missing something.

My attempt:

I started by defining $|X_n|^{1+\sigma} \leq Y $

Then
$$
\{|X_N|^{1+\sigma} \gt R\} \subseteq \{Y \gt R\}
$$
Therefore
$$
 \int_{|X_N|^{1+\sigma} \gt R} |X_N|^{1+\sigma}\,dP \leq \int_{|X_N|^{1+\sigma} \gt R} Y \,dP \leq \int_{Y \gt R} |Y| \,dP 
$$
Implying
$$
\sup\int_{|X_N|^{1+\sigma} \gt R} |X_N|^{1+\sigma}\,dP \leq \int_{Y \gt R} |Y| \,dP 
$$

Does following this pattern make sense? Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a well-known fact.

Proposition: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space.
Let $\mathcal{C}=\{X_{i}\mid i\in\Lambda\}$ be a family of random
variables (that family may be uncountable). If there exists $p\in(1,\infty)$
such that
$$
\sup_{i\in\Lambda}\int|X_{i}|^{p}\,dP<\infty,
$$
then $\mathcal{C}$ is uniformly integrable.

Proof: Let $l=\sup_{i\in\Lambda}\int|X_{i}|^{p}\,dP$. Let $q\in(1,\infty)$
be such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be
arbitrary. Choose $c>0$ such that $l^{\frac{1}{p}}\cdot\left(\frac{l}{c^{p}}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}<\varepsilon$,
which is possible because $l^{\frac{1}{p}}\cdot\left(\frac{l}{t^{p}}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\rightarrow0$
as $t\rightarrow\infty$. Define $A_{i}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid|X_{i}(\omega)|\geq c\}$.
Observe that
\begin{eqnarray*}
l & \geq & \int_{A_{i}}|X_{i}|^{p}\,dP\\
 & \geq & P(A_{i})c^{p}.
\end{eqnarray*}
That is, $P(A_{i})\leq\frac{l}{c^{p}}.$ On the other hand, by Holder
inequality,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{A_{i}}|X_{i}|\,dP & = & \int|X_{i}|\cdot 1_{A_{i}}\,dP\\
 & \leq & ||X_{i}||_{p}||1_{A_{i}}||_{q}\\
 & \leq & l^{\frac{1}{p}}\left\{ P(A_{i})\right\} ^{\frac{1}{q}}\\
 & \leq & l^{\frac{1}{p}}\left(\frac{l}{c^{p}}\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\\
 & < & \varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore,
$$
\sup_{i\in\Lambda}\int_{A_{i}}|X_{i}|\,dP\leq\varepsilon
$$
and hence $\mathcal{C}$ is uniformly integrable.

Comment: And in this case we just let p = 1+ $\sigma$ and the result follows, correct?

Comment: Quick notation question -- in the line $\leq ||X_i||_p||1_{A_i}||_q$ is that representing the p-th and q-th norms?

Comment: Yes. $||\cdot||_p$ is the usual $p$-norm for the Lebesgue space $L^p$.

Answer (score 1):

This can't help you since the sharpest bound you don't know anything about $Y$ other than lower bounds on it but to achieve integrability you need upper bounds. Instead, as a hint, you want to control $$\sup_{n} \int_{|X_n| > R} |X_n| d\mathbb{P}$$ and you have control on $|X_n|^{1+\sigma}$ so you should consider applying Holder's inequality to bound the above integral.

Comment: would you mind providing a little more help, I'm having trouble applying holder to bound the integral. Sorry I am new to measure theory and struggling somewhat.

Comment: It appears the other answer has given a complete proof rather than a hint already. Just take $p= 1+\sigma$ there